# What was the structure of Hermogenes’ ‘Art of Rhetoric’ prior to the 6th C CE?

Tags: hermogenes

In her book, *Hermogenes and the Renaissance*, Annabel Patterson cites a paper by George Kustas ([‘The Function and Evolution of Byzantine Rhetoric’ in Viator, University of California Press, Vol I, 1970](http://www.brepolsonline.net/doi/abs/10.1484/J.VIATOR.2.301708?journalCode=viator)) that discusses the structure of *Art of Rhetoric*.

In her summary of the paper (n6, pp 6/7), Patterson states, without elaborating further, that:

> it was in the sixth century that the body of Hermogenes’ work was divided into the sections now recognised.

Hence the question: what was the structure of Hermogenes’ *Art of Rhetoric* prior to this?

Comment: Is this [Hermogenes of Tarsus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermogenes_of_Tarsus)?  Works from Classical Antiquity prior to ~200 CE [didn't have much in the way of punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation#Western_Antiquity) so the original texts, while they may have been broken up into sections, *On legal issues*, *On the invention of arguments*, etc., were probably just a single, undivided string of words.

Comment: Can you add the Greek title of the work you are referring to? Is it *Περὶ τῶν στάσεων* or *Περὶ μεθόδου δεινότητος* (Greek titles copied from the [French Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermog%C3%A8ne_de_Tarse#.C5.92uvre)). Even better, add this to the tag wiki for [tag:hermogenes-art-of-rhetoric].

Comment: It turns out that Patterson misquotes Kustas.

Comment: Kustas writes 'The present corpus of five treatises was first put together in the late fifth or early sixth century, and many progymnasmata written at the time became attached to his name.' The corpus is listed (n 4, p 56) as 'Προγυμνάσματα, Περὶ στάσεων, Περὶ εὑρέσεως, Περὶ ἰδεῶν, Περὶ μεθόδου δεινότητος', remarking that 'Rabe consideres the Προγυμνάσματα and the Περὶ εὑρέσεως spurious'.

Comment: I think you can submit your two last comments as an answer to your own question, especially if you can add a reference.